# import statements fail

Tags: deployment, puppet

I'm a Puppet newbie.  I'm trying to setup a chef-style deployment environment.  I have a puppet-master server set up, and I'd like to be able to configure/deploy to two nodes that I set up simultaneously.

What I'm expecting with my puppet setup right now is for my two servers (called img01 and img02) to automatically create a file called /tmp/test_file.txt.

I'm not even sure how to really "load in" a manifest.  I just assumed that anything in site.pp would automatically get loaded, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  When I run "puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp", I get the following:

```
Error: Could not parse for environment production: No file(s) found for import of 'test' at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:3 on node puppet.lgwp.com
Error: Could not parse for environment production: No file(s) found for import of 'test' at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:3 on node puppet.lgwp.com
```

This is what my manifest setup looks like right now:

**Cert list on the puppet-master server:**

```
+ "img01.lgwp.com.com"  (SHA256) (omitted)
+ "img02.lgwp.com"  (SHA256) (omitted)
+ "puppet.lgwp.com" (SHA256) (omitted) (alt names: "DNS:puppet.lgwp.com")
```

**/etc/puppet/manifest/site.pp:**

```
import "test" 

import "nodes"

Exec { path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin/:/bin:/sbin" }
```

**/etc/puppet/manifest/nodes.pp:**

```
import "test"

node "imageserver" {
  include "tempfile"
}

node 'img01.lgwp.com' inherits imageserver {
}
node 'img02.lgwp.com' inherits imageserver {
}
```

**/etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/test.pp:**

```
class test {

  package { test: ensure => latest }

  file { "test_file":
    path => '/tmp/test_file.txt',
    ensure => present,
    mode => 0755,
    content => 'hola world',
    source => "puppet:///modules/test/test_file",
    require => Package["test"],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use import. Just don't.

Remove the existing `import` statements and change the `manifest` setting in your `puppet.conf` to include all files in `/etc/puppet/manifests`.

```
[main]
manifest=/etc/puppet/manifests/
```

`include tempfile` makes no sense either, unless you have a `tempfile` module. Try

```
include test
```

Other classes in the `test` module should be named `test::something` and can also just be included. Puppet locates the manifests in the according modules. There is literally no need to use `import` anymore.